# Read command line from char

Tags: c++

I want to create a program capable of reading the command line in format:
SET x = ( expression )  <--- spaces between everywhere

without using strings. I wanted to cin in the command and simply compare it to a list of possible values, 
so..

```
char a;
cin>>a;
if(a== 'SET'){
----
}
```

this obviously does not work because a is an array.
I thought i could do it this way (if a[0]=='S'), then check a[1] for 'E' etc. but I believe this is a widely inefficient way of doing this? or isnt it?

Comment: Could you give a much more clear example of what you want to do and what you want it to do?
Are you wanting it to evaluate an expression from the command line?

Comment: You seem to be looking for `strcmp` from the C library.

Comment: why don't you want to use `string` - is it because there is something about `string` that doesn't meet your needs, or because you want to figure it out "from scratch" or because you've been told you can't use it?

Comment: Or he is just curious?

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you can use `std::string`

```
std::string a;
cin >> a;
if (a.compare("SET"))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

`string::compare` will do an equality comparison for the full string instead of character-by-character comparison.

Comment: He asked to do it without strings. (I didn't downvote you though!)

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to do it from the command line, as well. Also, you missed the "std::" before "cin"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strcmp function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char * a;
    std::cin >> a;
    if (strcmp(a, "SET") == 0) {
        std::cout << "check" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```